# GoogleMap object is unable to obtain location on a new version of the app?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i am building an android app that is just like the ***Google Maps*** app. It stores locations,routes etc. I moved my eclipse project from my ***Linux/Ubuntu*** system to ***Mac OSX*** system,and obtained a new api key for my project. I was testing my application with my own android device, ***Samsung Galaxy Note2*** .It was working, ***GoogleMap*** object was able to obtain location;but now its unable to obtain location. I used my brother's android phone , ***Galaxy Note1*** , to test the app , but its working properly on his device. ***GoogleMap*** object is unable to obtain location on my phone, but it obtains location on my brother's phone 
with same apk package installation.

I thought my phone has some old application data that causes this problem, and i did a factory reset. It's still the same. Is there any way to clean my phone, or do i have to do something on eclipse configurations?

Comment: can you show your code ???

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same APK signed with the same keys on different test devices and only one device is working, it's probably the device's GPS that is not getting a GPS lock.

To test, open Google Maps or any other app that uses GPS features on the device that is not displaying your app's maps, and see if that app can get a GPS lock. If it does, I suggest you check your app's signing keys on the API console and make sure you have all your keys registered.

Comment: Google Maps app is able to display location on my device. I checked over and over again, keys are correct. MapFragment shows, google map shows, but it cant get my location. MyLocation button of the GoogleMap  is also not working. What confuses me is that it works on my brother's phone :/